# how to get Authorization code from callback URL after Login in the portal using Authorization code flow grant type in OAuth2.0

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract Authorization code from the callback URL after Login in the portal, using Authorization code flow grant type in OAuth2.0 using Web driver sampler. The issue here is that after login, the Authorization code URL is disappearing immediately and the user detail page is appearing as landing page, since Authorization code URL is not appearing as Landing page that's why I am not able extract the authorization code via regular expression.

Please suggest me how to approach, if I can not extract it from URL, then can I get the network calls and parse the Auth code from Jmeter,if yes then how ! @Dmitri T

Tried using Web driver sampler and extracting the Auth code using Regular expression

Answer (score 0):

If you're not capable of intercepting the authorization code from URL you can consider using [Performance Log](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log) and then you will be able to extract it from the log entries.

In general using the real browser is not the best idea because they're very resource intensive, i.e. [Firefox 114](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/114.0/system-requirements/) requires 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per instance so a better idea would be [configuring JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and just simulate browser's network footprint. All static values like `client_id` can be set in [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) and dynamic values can be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).