# how to run 2000 users in jmeter while i am having 20 users in my csv file?

Tags: jmeter, multiple-users

I have a requirement to run 2000 users for 1 hr and i have 20 real users in my csv file, so how can i run it so after every 20 users, if will again run those 20 users in a loop till 2000 users running completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given default [Sharing Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779544/how-to-get-authorization-code-from-callback-url-after-login-in-the-portal-using/76779745#76779745) of `All Threads` in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) JMeter will read the next line on each iteration of each virtual user.

So just make sure that:

1. **Recycle on EOF** is set to `True` and **Stop thread on EOF** is set to `False`

   [image]
2. The number of users multiplied by the Loop Count in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is equal to 2000

   [image]

In general ideally if you need to mimic 2000 users you should have 2000 credentials so it worth checking whether it's possible to generate 1980 more test accounts.

Comment: "...ideally if you need to mimic 2000 users you should have 2000 credentials..." -- Indeed. Twenty sample values/credentials may not be enough to get a realistic/valid result for 2000 threads.

Comment: thank you so much. yes you are right. will create 2000 real users and then check